# Como montar um fomulario reativo através de um input radio?

Tags: html, typescript, formulário, programação-reativa

Galera, podem me ajudar?

Eu montei um componente radio e dependendo do valor dele será renderizado um novo formulário, segue meu HTML

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4 center-zone">
    <msp-radio-group id="caracteristicas" theme="boolean" label="Tem caracteristicas?" (click)="formReactive($event)"></msp-radio-group>
  </div>

  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-3" *ngIf="maisCaracteristicas">
    <msp-input-text id="teste" label="teste" tooltip="ajustar"></msp-input-text>
  </div>
```

E meu ts:

```
formReactive(event: any) {
console.log(event)
if (event.value) {
  this.seguro = true;
}
else {
  this.seguro = false;
}
```

}

Ou seja, que que se o valor Boolean for **SIM** ele renderize o campo ***teste***, caso contrario, ele não renderize.

Não sei o que fiz de errado, pois não esta funcionando, podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, acredito que você esteja fazendo a condição de "mostrar" no campo errado. 
Tendo em vista que você quer esconder o elemento o "ngIf" deve estar ligado a  variável
Veja :

```html
<div ngIf="seguro"> .... seu conteudo aqui </div>
```

Ou em qual variável você tiver definido na sua classe de controle.
[Verifique este link para entender sobre o ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)
[Este outro link fala sobre eventos](https://www.positronx.io/useful-list-of-angular-7-event-types-for-event-binding/)